# Get correct static urls with cherrypy dispatching of flask apps

Tags: python, flask, url-routing, cherrypy, static-files

I'm trying to use cherrypy for [application dispatching](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/appdispatch/) with Flask. The docs give an example with a development server, but when using the [cherrypy example snippet](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/24/) and modifying the url prefix, the page is unable to find the static folder.

My directory structure is as follows:

```
cherry
├── app1
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── app1.py
├── app2
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── app2.py
│   ├── static
│   │   └── js.js
│   └── templates
│       └── index.html
└── cherry_app.py
```

Some relevant files:

```
##  cherry_app.py
from cherrypy import wsgiserver
from app1.app1 import app as app1
from app2.app2 import app as app2

d = wsgiserver.WSGIPathInfoDispatcher({'/first': app1,
                                       '/second': app2,
                                       })

server = wsgiserver.CherryPyWSGIServer(('0.0.0.0', 9999), d)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        print 'Start at 0.0.0.0:9999'
        server.start()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        server.stop()


##  app2.py
from flask import Flask, send_file
import flask

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/")
def root():
    return ("Hello World!\nThis is the second app. Url is %s"
            % flask.url_for('root'))

@app.route("/index")
def index():
    return send_file('templates/index.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()


##  index.html
<script src="/static/js.js"></script>

JS loaded?

##  js.js
alert('Loaded!');
```

Going to `http://0.0.0.0:9999/second/` correctly tells me that the `Url is /second/`, and the javascript is loaded when I go to `http://0.0.0.0:9999/second/static/js.js`. But the html gives the error `GET http://0.0.0.0:9999/static/js.js 404 (Not Found)`. It appears it doesn't know to use the prefix `/second` when looking for `/static` even when I change the line:

```
app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='/second/static')
```

How can I get the webpage to correctly load the static files? Preferrably without html templating (like jinja).

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to use `url_for` to locate static files? Here is the [static files section](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#static-files) in Flask quickstart.

So in your situation, modify `src` value of `script` element in index.html:

```
<script src="{{ url_for("static", "js.js") }}"></script>
```

The second argument `js.js` should be the relative path of static file (say js.js) to the static folder. So if the directory structure of static looks like:

```
static/scripts/js.js
```

just replace `js.js` with `scripts/js.js`:

```
<script src="{{ url_for("static", "scripts/js.js") }}"></script>
```

Hope this will make sense.

Comment: `url_for` works correctly (first route in `app2.py`), but I'd like a way that doesn't involve templating (last sentence), since it's given me too much trouble with Angular...if there's no other way I may go with this, though.